# simple natural log calculation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to calculate for

$y = x^2 \ln(x)$ for $x \ge 1$

I'm getting confused with the correct approach to this.

What I have tried:

$\frac{dy}{dx}= 2x \cdot \frac{1}{x}$

Or:

$\exp{y}=x^{2}x$; $\frac{dy}{dx}\exp{y} = x^{3}$; = $\frac{x^{3}}{\exp{y}}$?

Essentially, I want to calculate $x$ at $1.2$, what is the appropriate expansion to figure out the result?

Comment: Don't forget the product rule: $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$.

Comment: So for taking the derivative of $x^2\ln x$ you should end up with two terms; the first term should be $2x\ln x$.

Comment: At the start you should say what you are trying to calculate.  Later it becomes clear you want to take the derivative.

Comment: Yes, the derivative of $x^2 ln(x)$ is $2x ln(x)+ x^2(1/x)= 2x ln(x)+ x$.  Your other calculation, that $exp(y)= e^y= x^3$ is also wrong.  $y= x^2 ln(x)= ln(x^{x^2})$ so $exp(y)= x^{x^2}$.  I recommend that you review logariths!

Comment: @HallsofIvy You're right, although I don't think I asked the question properly. I eventually figured out it required the chain-rule for differentiation. However, I noticed this wasn't what I was looking for. I'm trying to work out $x^{2}lnx$ when $x = 1.2$ which should be $0.2625$ in series expansion form.

Comment: @no_'t'-lime Maybe you wanted $(1+x)^2\ln(1+x)=x+\frac{3 x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+O\left(x^4\right)$ at $x=0.2$ which gives $0.2626$

Comment: Why on earth does this have the **pre**calculus tag?

Comment: "I'm trying to calculate for $y=x^2\ln(x)$"  You are trying do calculate *what* for $y=x^2\lnx$?

Answer (score 1):

Assume you left out the words $\color{red}{\text{the derivative}}$ in the sentence "$\text{I'm trying to calculate }\color{red}{\text{the derivative}}\text{ for}$"

You seem to some very fundamental "freshman dreams" about distribution across multiplication.

$[f(x)g(x)]' \ne f'(x)g'(x)$

And $\exp (f(x)g(x))\ne f(x)exp(g(x))$.

To be blunt these are very naive errors, and there is no reason you should have ever have made them.

In calculus (why on earth is the tag *pre*calculus) you should have learned the product rule and you should know it backwards and forward in your sleep.

> $[f(x)g(x)] = f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x)$.

So you should be able to rattle off:

> $[x^2\ln x]= (x^2)'\ln x + (x^2)\ln' x = 2x\ln x + x^2\frac 1x = 2x\ln x +x$

if you like you can (probably should) factor

> $= x(2\ln x + 1)$.